# JQuery: How to disable mouse over scrolling on all <select> elements on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouseevent, mouseover

the code below doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing here?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    //disables scrolling on mouse over of <select> elements
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('onmousewheel', 'return false;');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    //disables scrolling on mouse over of <select> elements
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').each(function() {
            $(this).on('mousewheel', function(){
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow answered so fast I can't even accept it yet. Many thanks MISJHA!

Answer (score 1):

onmousewheel is not really a attribute of SELECT HTML Element. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

You are trying to set Mouse event. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

You can achieve this in the way MISJHA pointed.

Comment: Funny I was just reading that page a few minutes ago, and yes you guys are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/). It removes the attached DOM attribute